# DatePicker ant design - disable the current/todays date

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

How do you disable the current/today's date with DatePicker in the [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) library? I need to move the default date back one day (I successfully did this) and disable the current day and all days in the future. I have it really close, except I can't seem to disable the current/today? Can you not do that?

This is what I'm trying?

```
private disabledDate = (current) => {
    return current && current >= moment().endOf('day');
}
....
<DatePicker
    defaultValue={moment().subtract(1, 'day')}
    value={moment(this.state.reportPeriod, dateFormat)}
    format={'MMM D, YYYY'}
    disabledDate={this.disabledDate}
    onChange={this.selectDate}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Ant Designs example page has an example of this on [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001). Their function can be found below (assuming you're trying to disable today and days in the past. If you're looking for today and in the future, just use `>` instead of `<`.

```
function disabledDate(current) {
  // Can not select days before today and today
  return current && current < moment().endOf('day');
}
```

Edit: So the function to disable today and all future dates is:

```
function disabledDate(current) {
  return current && current > moment().startOf('day');
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I should have clarified, I need to disable all dates in the future including today

Comment: I updated my answer to account for this additional data. Please note that I also changed the moment call to `startOf('day')` which looking back on it now, is probably your only real problem in your code.

Comment: that makes sense on the surface but on my end you can still pick today as a date